# Window latch? What are these called and where can I buy them?

Tags: windows, lock

My windows has 3 of these per window, positioned top middle and bottom on the inside of the window frame. These catch the lock on the window to secure the closed position.

However on some windows, I've noticed I'm missing some of these as seems like the screws have broken in the hole it once held these in.

I'm planning to replace them by carefully drilling a new holes to secure these things in, slightly above/below the old holes.

I'm in the UK and looking to find where I can get replacements? Can you advise what my best approach is?

[image]

Comment: did you google the part number?

Comment: **We can not begin to do your research for you if you do not provide at least a little info, what kind of window it is, slider, swing out, older, newer, makers mark**.  *A photo of the corresponding lever that engages this part*. The **best approach** is to try to figure out who the manufacturer of the window is and contact them directly, It may *take some time and work on your part* to figure out where and if you can buy them. If you do find them then you can post a question with details on how to repair the holes and mount the new part.

Comment: looks like it's called "SW71024"  it's probably specific to that make of windows.